# Appending NSAttributedString with line break returns attributed string with wrong format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I'm using `NSMutableAttributedString` and `NSAttributedString` to display a label text in two different font sizes. My approach is:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *muAtrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"2"];
NSAttributedString *atrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"days" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];
[muAtrStr appendAttributedString:atrStr];
```

Which returns me an Attributed string with "2" in font size 12 and "days" in font size 8.

However, the other scenario is to add a line break after 2. I use the following code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *muAtrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"2"];
NSAttributedString *atrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\ndays" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];
[muAtrStr appendAttributedString:atrStr];
```

This time attributed string applies the attribute on the full text. I get an attributed string with "2\ndays" in font size 8.

Comment: Please guide me if there is a better approach to do the needful.

Comment: You can also use `- (void)addAttribute:(NSString *)name value:(id)value range:(NSRange)range` method of attributed string to set attribute to different part of attributed string. And `setLineBreakMode` of label to `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`.

Comment: For those who was stuck like me, set yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0; in the code.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this below code, it works fine:-

```
NSMutableAttributedString *muAtrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"2"];
NSAttributedString *atrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\ndays" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];
[muAtrStr appendAttributedString:atrStr];
self.lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.lbl setAttributedText:muAtrStr];
```

Note:- Also put numberOfLines to 0 for allowing any number of lines

Comment: But in UILabel it is displaying both 2 and days in same font size i-e 8. I want to display 2 in 12 font size and days in 8 font size.

Comment: just for the "days" text. 12 font size is default for the "2" string. Working perfect when I don't use \n in the string.

Comment: sorry, it didn't work either... Might work for text view, not working for uilabel.

Comment: yes, also the uilabel displays both strings i-e 2 & days in the same font, No change

Comment: using iOS7.1 and setting the attributed text as you described.

Comment: You do not have to set numberOfLines to 0, and you can just set the property  to 2

Comment: Thank you very much.This is so helpful for us.

Comment: ahhh, those numberOfLines!

Answer (score 14):

This works in Swift:

```
let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Happy \nDays")
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
label.attributedText = attributedText
```